# Camel: Tracing history of exchanges when a splitter is used

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel, and trying to create a log of the history of the processing of each message in a workflow.

For simple straight-through workflows, where a message comes in, is processed by a few steps, and then leaves, this could be as simple as just keeping a sequential log of the exchanges.  I can do this by writing a custom TraceEventHandler, which is called at each exchange and allows me to do logging.

However, if a splitter is involved, I don't know how to calculate the provenance of any given exchange.  I could maintain my own log of exchanges, but in the case of a splitter, not all previous activity would be an ancestor of the current exchange.  That is, if an incoming message is split into part1 and part2, which are then each processed separately, I don't want to consider the processing of part1 when calculating the history of part2.

A TraceEventHandler has this method:

```
@Override
public void traceExchange(ProcessorDefinition<?> node, Processor target, 
  TraceInterceptor traceInterceptor,Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
}
```

and I expected that there would be an Exchange method like `Exchange getPreviousExchange()` that I could call inside traceExchange, but I can find no such thing.

Any advice?  I'm not married to using a custom TraceEventHandler if there's a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track the post-split processing as separate branches, then you need to consider the Camel property "CamelSplitIndex". This property will indicate which iteration of the split you're processing and when combined with the CamelCorrelationId as William suggested, will provide the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the previous Exchange id by looking up the exchange property with the key "CamelCorrelationId".